# Python , how to get value from a loop and assign to another loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

I have two loops below  the first one is the timand and the second one is shared. What i want to know how can i assign each result to shared["score"] ? cause what i had try below i assign shared["score"] = timang["score"] just return  1 1 1 .... And also how can we return multiple response in python for example

return Response(shared_data, tomon_dat,  status=status.HTTP_200_OK) is this possible?

```
#result of timang

    Result: 0
    Result: 1
    Result: 0
    Result: 0
    Result: 1
    Result: 1


for timang in tomon_dat:
                tm_ins = QuestionaireAnswerModel.objects.get(id=timang["id"])
                timang["score"] = tm_ins.score
                timang["id"] = tm_ins.id
                datatest = timang["score"]




            for shared in shared_data:
                questionaire_ins = QuestionaireModel.objects.get(random_code=shared["random_code"])
                shared["title"] = questionaire_ins.title
                shared["sub_title"] = questionaire_ins.sub_title

                shared["idddd"] = questionaire_ins.id

                answer_ins = SharedQuestionaire.objects.get(id=shared["id"])
                shared["is_answered"] = (QuestionaireAnswerModel.objects.filter(shared_questionaire=answer_ins).count()) > 0
                shared["score"] = timang["score"]
```

Comment: please indent your code properly

Comment: Withi current indentation, the reason it is returning 1 1 1 is because you have a `nested loop`. Which means say `timang` loop runs `n` time and `shared` loops run `m` time, `shared["score"]` will return response for `m*n` times where each value will repeat for `m` times.

Comment: what would be a good solution Sir?

Comment: You do this line for each timang `shared["score"] = timang["score"]` which means that all scores will get the same timang